# is there already any system out there that works as a widget manager for a website?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, frameworks, widget

I'm building a website that separates functionality into specific widgets... and I want to be able to drag an instance or multiple instances of a particular widget, that I will build, onto the screen for use. a bit like the apple widget system, but for websites. are there any frameworks or library's already out there that do this?

any help with this or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Widget Factory is simple enough to use as a starting point, they work similar to jQuery plugin and since all of your widgets will be inheriting from jQuery Widget, you wont have any problems integrating them where needed.

[MSDN Site with jQuery Widget tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404085.aspx)
[jQuery Widget website](http://jqueryui.com/widget/)